# Is there a way to change thickness of v-divider?

Tags: javascript, css, vuetify.js

I don't know if I am using the thickness prop correctly or if there is a better way to do this.

```
<v-divider :thickness="var"/>
```

Comment: The question is a bit odd: what happens if you use it? And what exactly do you mean when you say "to do this"? Please be more precise. And have you done any docs research?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, the docs state:

> Prop Name: thickness
> Type: any
> Default: undefined
> Description: Sets the dividers thickness. Default unit is px.

```
<v-divider thickness="20px" />
```

Or, since you are using `v-bind`, your dynamic prop 'var' should be renamed to let's say 'thicknessVal' and declared like this in the script part: `thickness: '20px'`.

See https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-divider/#props-thickness and https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dividers/#props.
The latter source even has an example that you can open directly in codepen where you can test it.